# Clarification regarding self

Tags: python

In methods when is it necessary to use notation like self.variable_name? For instance, I know that in the constructor method it needs to be like

```
class A(object):
     def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
```

in order to give it an instance variable. However, what about in other methods? When do I need to put self in front of a variable name and when is it okay to just use a variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You must always put a `self` as the first argument of an instance method. This is what you use to access the instance variables.

It is similar to `this` in other languages, but different in that it is required whereas other languages will often have instance variables in scope.

Comment: Well, not *always* (think `@staticmethod`, `@classmethod`)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are wanting to access attributes of the particular object of type A.  For example:

```
def get_name(self): # here, whenever this method is called, it expects 'self'.  
    return self.name
```

When calling this method outside of the class scope, python has **self** passed implicitly.

```
example = A('d_rez')
example.get_name()   # no arguments are passed, but self is passed implicitly to 
               # have access to all its attributes!
```

So to answer your question:  You need to pass self whenever you define a method inside a class, and this is usually because there are some attributes involved.  Otherwise, it could just be a static function defined outside the class if it doesn't pertain to a particular instance of class A.